# SoundCloud track.stream_url not working for some of the tracks

Tags: soundcloud

I noticed that on some tracks on soundcloud stream_url points to 404 - page not found.
The track is set as streamable, but still stream url is not working.

Here is an example: 
http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/129894766.json?consumer_key=KEY
returns `streamable: true, embeddable_by: "all"` but: `stream_url: "http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/129894766/stream?consumer_key=KEY"` is not working.

Has anyone experienced this and maybe have some solution?

Answer (score 3):

The reason the stream URL isn't working for certain tracks is that they use different streaming protocols (RTMP / HLS). SoundCloud is in the process of updating their SDK's and documentation for this, but the current (2.0) version of the Javascript SDK should fix this issue for now.

Comment: I have the same problem as @cucko with several tracks, e.g. [this one](https://soundcloud.com/octobersveryown/drake-days-in-the-east). I'm using soundcloud's javascript SDK but it's not solving anything... Any other recommendation @Marco?

Comment: from what i've found, rtmp can't be streamed in web browser only with javascript. soundcloud javascript api is using flash fallback for rtmp. it's big step backwards.

Comment: To be more precise: The 2.0 API has to be explicitly addressed. The default API is still 1.0, which is also the API described in the JavaScript SDK Basic Use section. The JS for version 2.0 can be found at connect.soundcloud.com/sdk-2.0.0.js. See here for changes: https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/javascript-sdk-2.