# SoundCloud some stream_url respond with 404

Tags: soundcloud

For more and more tracks I am getting a 404 Not found error when I try to get the streamUrl from the server. Here is a example track metadata:

```
{
    "artwork_url" = "https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000085702287-cv13f5-large.jpg?e76cf77";
    "attachments_uri" = "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/159486887/attachments";
    "comment_count" = 4;
    commentable = 1;
    "created_at" = "2014/07/20 09:44:24 +0000";
    description = "As premiered by Friction on BBC Radio 1 & 1Xtra.\n\nIt\U2019s time for some no nonsense drum & bass on MTA Records, courtesy of Mob Tactics with \U2018The Answer\U2019 EP. The duo seem to be a name on people\U2019s lips more and more of late. Already renowned for their own inimitable style of techy \U2013 yet very funky, dance-floor orientated drum & bass, the duo appear to be going from strength-to-strength with each release, and \U2018The Answer\U2019 EP takes them in to a musical world which they have not yet explored.\n\n\U2018The Answer\U2019 EP is set to turn some heads, with the tracks already firm staples in the sets of Chase & Status, Andy C & Friction to name but a few, and the demand for them on the DJ circuit is rapidly gaining momentum. \U2018The Answer\U2019 EP will be released as a Beatport exclusive 28th July.\n\nMob Tactics:\nhttp://facebook.com/MobTacticsMusic\nhttp://soundcloud.com/mob-tactics\nhttp://twitter.com/Mob_Tactics";
    "download_count" = 0;
    downloadable = 0;
    duration = 248002;
    "embeddable_by" = all;
    "favoritings_count" = 43;
    genre = "Drum & Bass";
    id = 159486887;
    kind = track;
    license = "all-rights-reserved";
    "original_content_size" = 12521587;
    "original_format" = mp3;
    permalink = "mob-tactics-mirror-mirror-1";
    "permalink_url" = "http://soundcloud.com/mtarecords/mob-tactics-mirror-mirror-1";
    "playback_count" = 398;
    sharing = public;
    state = finished;
    "stream_url" = "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/159486887/stream";
    streamable = 1;
    "tag_list" = "";
    title = "Mob Tactics - Mirror Mirror";
    uri = "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/159486887";
    user =     {
        "avatar_url" = "https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000070023934-p6ghqx-large.jpg?e76cf77";
        id = 260041;
        kind = user;
        permalink = mtarecords;
        "permalink_url" = "http://soundcloud.com/mtarecords";
        uri = "https://api.soundcloud.com/users/260041";
        username = "MTA Records";
    };
    "user_favorite" = 0;
    "user_id" = 260041;
    "user_playback_count" = 1;
    "waveform_url" = "https://w1.sndcdn.com/h0xcO78NsIsL_m.png";
}
```

But when I try to get the stream with help of this method call:

```
id obj = [SCRequest performMethod:SCRequestMethodGET
                       onResource:track.stream_url
                  usingParameters:nil
                      withAccount:[SCSoundCloud account]
           sendingProgressHandler:^(unsigned long long bytesSend, unsigned long long bytesTotal) {
               NSLog(@"%llu", bytesTotal / bytesSend);
           }
                  responseHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *responseData, NSError *error) {
                      if (error) {
                          NSLog(@"%@ ->\n    %@", url, error.description);
                      } else {
                          NSSound *player = [[NSSound alloc] initWithData:responseData];
                          [delegate apiController:[APIController sharedController] didFinishWithPlayer:player];
                      }
                  }
          ];
```

I am always getting this error:

```
https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/159486887/stream ->
    Error Domain=NXOAuth2HTTPErrorDomain Code=404 "HTTP Error: 404" UserInfo=0x61800027a5c0 {NSLocalizedDescription=HTTP Error: 404}
```

That way sadly I can't listen to half of the tracks, even if they are marked as: streamable = 1;

Comment: It has been asked 8 months ago already but @SCsupport asked me to reask it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19852634/soundcloud-api-why-are-stream-urls-for-a-particular-artist-not-working-anymore

Comment: I also posted it on Github https://github.com/soundcloud/CocoaSoundCloudAPI/issues/25

Comment: And I also tried to adding client_id to the URL like some people on the Internet suggest, without any success. curl -I https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/159486887/stream\?client_id\=e4baf129b35... ➜ HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Comment: Here 6 months ago somebody got some information about some streams only available via rtmp/hls http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21682231/soundcloud-track-stream-url-not-working-for-some-of-the-tracks?rq=1